# how to change the database to mongodb from sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to use the mongodb with ruby on rails

whenever i try to create the new project with

```
rails new exRuby
```

preference will be set to sqlite3 in /exRuby/config/database.yml file And automatically "gem 'sqlite3' added to Gem file

But I am trying to use the mongodb with my project. and mongodb is already installed in my system

How to change the database storage to mongodb from sqlite3

Comment: Which MongoDB interface are you going to use? Mongoid? MongoMapper? Something else? The interface's docs should tell you everything you need to know to setup Rails to use them.

Comment: The Mongoid docs have a ["Getting Rid of Active Record" section](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) on the installation page, have you read the docs?

Comment: @muistooshort i am reading the docs now. but when i create new project by default its taking sqlite3

Comment: i removed sqlite3 from gem file and added 'mongo' and 'mongoid' to gemfile then 'bundle install' after that when i tried 'rails g' i got the following errors http://pastebin.com/VCdw0jXT

Answer (score 1):

Like 'mu is too short' stated, you need to decide which MongoDB interface / gem you want to use to connect to MongoDB. [Here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) is a guide on how to setup a ruby app using Mongoid.

You can run the command `rails g mongoid:config` to generate the `mongoid.yml` file. But this is if you choose to use Mongoid. Look at the other gems available and see which one you prefer. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/#object-mappers) is a list of available options (according to the MongoDB docs).